# How to add link (html) into feature description?

Tags: cucumber

I hope you are fine today !

After several attempt we didn't find a way to add html link into the comment section of the feature.

[image]

As workaround we succed to add links before/after Scenarios but that quite far from the original expectation.

Any idea on this topic ? Thank you a lot in advance !